# Algebra norm properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be finite-dimensional associative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. What are the properties that must hold for $\|\cdot\|$ to be a norm on $A$? I assume we need:

- For all $x,y \in A$, $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\|+\|y\|$
- For all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in A$, $\|ax\| = |a|\|x\|$
- For all $x \in A$, $x=0$ if and only if $\|x\|=0$

I can't find the definition of a norm on an algebra anywhere, so I would appreciate a reference if possible.

Comment: @user251257 Indeed, but I didn't know whether there was any property regarding $\|xy\|$.

Comment: @rschwieb I was searching "algebra norm" rather than "norm algebra," which only yields results for norms on vector spaces.

Comment: @kccu The normal definition of "normed algebra" *only* concerns submultiplicativeness of the norm. Generally a vector-space-type norm is not the one used.

Comment: @kccu OK, well there ya go. That should have been your second search.

Comment: @rschwieb Are you saying the properties I listed in my question are not required? Only the submultiplicative property?

Comment: You will find out if you ever perform the search I suggested. Or check wikipedia's entry on "normed algebra". Or nLab's.

Comment: I did, but I am getting conflicting/unclear results. Wikipedia says a normed algebra has a "sub-multiplicative __norm__." Does that "norm" mean a vector space norm? nLab says a normed algebra is a "normed vector space" such that the norm satisfies $\|ab\| \leq C \|a\|\|b\|$. This suggests it _is_ a vector space norm. But your first comment _sounds_ like you're implying that sub-multiplicativity is the only property. Hence why I asked you to clarify.

Comment: I meant that the submultipivativity is the only thing special to normed *algebras*, not that it is the only axiom. I think all of the webpages I'm referring to are in agreement about this

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your comment. Thank you for the clarification.